# How to merge a used range from all Excel files in a folder?

Tags: c#, excel

Sorry to bother everyone if this is trivial, but I am stumped.  I put together some C# code that gets the used range from all Excel files in a folder and merges it into a single consolidated file.  The script mostly worked, but I noticed it was copying the headers from the source files.  So, I modified the script a bit.  Now, I am trying to copy the usedrange from the first file (which includes row 1), and then copy row 2 (and down) and all columns from the source files.  Below is my mostly working code.

I'm almost certain the problem is here.

```
  for (int i = 2; i <= rCnt; i++)
    {
    range = Worksheet.range[i, cCnt] as Excel.Range;
    if (range.Value != null)
      {
        Add(range.Value.ToString());
      }
    }
```

Here is the entire script.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Main();
        }

        public void Main()
        {                     
            string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\excel_files\\MainExcel.xlsx";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlobj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook w = default(Workbook);
            Workbook w1 = default(Workbook);
            Worksheet s = default(Worksheet);
            Worksheet s1 = default(Worksheet);
            Excel.Range range;
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;

            //Worksheet xlsht = default(Worksheet);
            int intItem = 1;                                                   
            DirectoryInfo dirSrc = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\excel_files\");
            foreach (FileInfo ChildFile in dirSrc.GetFiles())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Renaming the excel sheet
                    w = xlobj.Workbooks._Open(ChildFile.FullName,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    w1 = xlobj.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
                    xlobj.Visible = true;

                    w1 = xlobj.Workbooks._Open(filePath,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    // There is no sheets(2) in your MainExcel workbook when copying the 2nd workbook.
                    // if (intItem > 3)
                    // {
                    //     Excel.Worksheet lastSht =
                    //          (Excel.Worksheet)w1.Worksheets[w1.Worksheets.Count];
                    //     xlsht = (Excel.Worksheet)w1.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing,
                    //         lastSht, 
                    //         Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    // }
                    s = (Excel.Worksheet)w.Worksheets[1];
                    s1 = (Excel.Worksheet)w1.Worksheets[1];
                    s1.Name = ChildFile.Name;

                    // it will copy and paste sheet from one to another
                    // Excel.Range s = s.Cells[s.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1];
                    if (intItem == 1)
                        {
                        s.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
                        }   
                    else
                        {
                        range = s.UsedRange;
                        rCnt = range.Rows.Count;
                        cCnt = range.Columns.Count;

                            for (int i = 2; i <= rCnt; i++)
                            {
                                range = Worksheet.range[i, cCnt] as Excel.Range;
                                if (range.Value != null)
                                {
                                    Add(range.Value.ToString());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    // Excel.Range r = s1.Cells[1, 1];
                    // Excel.Range r = (s1.UsedRange.Row + s1.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1);
                    // Excel.Range r = s1.get_Range(s1.UsedRange.Row + 1, Type.Missing);
                    Excel.Range r = s1.Cells[s1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1];
                    r.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,
                          Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
                          Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    // with formula
                    // s1.UsedRange.Formula = s.UsedRange.Formula;

                    // Renaming the excel sheet
                    w.Save();
                    w1.Save();
                    w.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    w1.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    w.Save();
                    w1.Save();
                    w.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    w1.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                }
                intItem = intItem + 1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have a lot of comments here because I was testing several different ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit, I didn't deconstruct all of your code.  I see two, what appear to be syntax errors in the snippet you referenced as your likely problem area:

```
range = Worksheet.range[i, cCnt] as Excel.Range;
                  ^- I think that should be capitalized, as the indexer is
```

And...

```
Add(range.Value.ToString());
```

Where is the Add method?  This implies it's a method associated with the form class.

That said, I understand your end goal correctly, perhaps this is enough to do the trick.  I did this on a small list of files, and it copied each of the files to an new workbook, except for row 1 on all but the first of them.

It's a bit brute-force, in that I am actually copying the header row and then deleting it, but the code base is short and easy to maintain.

This is your `Main()` method:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlobj = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlobj.Visible = true;
xlobj.DisplayAlerts = false;

Excel.Workbook w = xlobj.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet sh = w.Worksheets[1];
int row = 1;

DirectoryInfo dirSrc = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\excel_files\");
foreach (FileInfo ChildFile in dirSrc.GetFiles())
{
    Excel.Workbook wb = xlobj.Workbooks.Open(ChildFile.FullName);
    Excel.Range r = wb.Worksheets[1].UsedRange;

    r.Copy();
    sh.Cells[row, 1].PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,
        Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone);

    if (row > 1)
        sh.Cells[row--, 1].EntireRow.Delete();

    row += r.Rows.Count;

    wb.Close();
}

w.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\excel_files\\MainExcel.xlsx");
```

Here's a screen shot of the before and after results:

[image]

Comment: Yeap, yeap, that did it!  Thanks so much!